# how to add style in angularjs based on condition in html itself

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I have the above page structure . i want to check a conditon to apply style in div with id if the buttonlayout has a class proceed.

```
<div>
  <div id="main">
</div>

<div id='buttonlayout" class="proceed">
</div>
```

I am displaying the `<div id='buttonlayout" class="proceed"></div>` based on some conditions. so if the div doesnt exist I dont want to apply sty;e. How can I check this in angular js?
So the logic I am looking for is

if `(.div-proceed)` exist add an extra style to div (with id main). Is it possible to check in my html page itself (ng-class)?

Comment: The div.proceed is displayed based on some condition. You want to apply a class if the div.proceed is visible. Thus, you also want to apply a class based on that same condition. That's what ng-class is for: `ng-class="{additional: someCondition}"`.

Comment: can you help me to write the condition to check if class "proceed" exist in the buttonlayout div .

Comment: A side note: You seem to have used different types of quotes for the `id` attibute. I recommend you stick with `"`.

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using Angular1.x or Angular2?

Comment: thanks . i will make use of "".

Comment: @HarshSharma version : 1.x

Comment: @JBNizet:is it possible to check it in html itself as an inline statement

Comment: No. The model is the single point of truth. Expressions are evaluated against the model, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can set conditions in `ng-class`, as sample `$scope.proceed` default is `false` our condition is when `$scope.proceed` is `true` add class `proceed` to the element.

This mean if `$scope.proceed = false` the class not exist, and if it `true` class is exist.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "$filter", function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.proceed = !$scope.proceed;
  }

}]);
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

a{cursor: pointer}


#buttonlayout {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#buttonlayout.proceed {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <a ng-click="change()">click to remove/add 'proceed' class</a>
  <div id="buttonlayout" ng-class="{'proceed': proceed}"></div>

</div>
```